# Wpf listbox resize issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, grid-layout

I got a user-control containing a grid with two rows. In each row there will be a listbox. The problem is that when items are getting added to the listbox then the control just keep expanding so the containing items and the listbox control in row two can't be seen anymore.

How do I make sure that the listbox controls doesn't expand without hardcoding a height ? Each row should have equal size and the controls should be resizable when the user is resizing the window.

I've tried a lot of things and different containers but haven't solved the issue yet.

Example code:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <GroupBox Header="Allowed Countries" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                    </ListBox>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Allowed Languages" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
                    </ListBox>
                </GroupBox>
            /Grid>
        </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The listbox items are hard-coded in this example but they'll be binded at runtime when I get the resize problem solved. The dockpanel is used 'cause there are other controls than the grid in the usercontrol.

Maybe I'm using the wrong control/container?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last worked with WPF, but I'm *believe* the behavior you're describing is the fault of the ScrollViewer control.

My thinking here is that the ScrolllViewer control would mean that WPF is not providing a hard limit to the height of the Dockpanel, and as such it (and its child controls) would grow as needed in spite of the height of the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting the height of the grid rows to (height of usercontrol / 2).